# Hash quality of 4-byte prefix of MD5SUM

Tags: md5, hashcode

I have an MD5 sum, but I need a 4-byte hash. Does anybody know whether it is better to use, for example, an XOR of 4-byte chunks of the MD5 or just the first 4 bytes of it.

My hunch is that the first 4 bytes should be as good as any other 4 bytes from the MD5 sum and that further mangling with XOR will not improve the hash. Explanation and pointers as to the "randomness" of parts of an MD5 sum appreciated.

This is not intended for cryptography, just for lookup in a hash table.

Comment: To give a good answer, it might be important to know how you are going to use the resulting hash. Is it just to reference data in a hash table for fast look-ups? Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @WimCoenen - I'm not sure that's necessary. The question is simply, is any 4-byte chunk of an MD5 as good as any other?

Comment: I'm just worried that the result is going to be used as if it is a cryptographically secure hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a 4-byte hash for hash table lookup or similar, then yes, the first four bytes (or any four bytes) are as good as any other combination. In fact, using MD5 is overkill, unless (as you imply) you already have the MD5 hash available for free.

Obviously four bytes are not enough for any kind of cryptographic signature, whatever algorithm you use. But you knew that, right?